# Add a row to table under active cell

Tags: excel, vba

First off: My intention is to add a row to the table, but under the current chosen row (So if i'm at row 4 in the table, i want my new row to be just below it at row 5). This is the table row and not the sheet row, just for clarification.

How does my code look:

```
Sub AddRow()
    Dim loTable As ListObject
    Dim lrRow As ListRow
    Dim lrPosition As Integer

    Set loTable = Selection.ListObject
    Set lrPosition = loTable.Range.Row

    Set lrRow = loTable.ListRows.Add (lrPosition, True)

End Sub
```

I can't figure out what is wrong. I tried changing the "Set lrPosition" line to Selection.ListObject.Range.Row, as that was the original code i found on the internet to solve the problem, but it didn't help.

Without the lines regarding lrPosition (and the specification of the Listrows.add function), it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`loTable.Range.Row` will return the start row of the table within the sheet, but what you need it the row number within the table - you can calculate it using the row number of the active cell. The `Set` you have written in your code is wrong, `Set` is used to assign object references, but not to assign single values.

```
Sub AddRow()
    Dim loTable As ListObject
    Dim lrRow As ListRow
    Dim lrPosition As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ' Check if we are within a table
    Set loTable = Selection.ListObject
    On Error GoTo 0
    If loTable Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    lrPosition = ActiveCell.Row - loTable.Range.Row + 1
    Set lrRow = loTable.ListRows.Add(lrPosition, True)
End Sub
```

I added a check that the code will exit when called while not being inside a table and changed the data type for `lrPosition` to `Long` - always use `Long` when dealing with row or column numbers to avoid overflow errors.